# Basic custom element does not seem to work

Tags: aurelia

I'm trying to create a standard user status widget for my Aurelia app, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  As a starting point I followed [the docs](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/templating/latest/templating-custom-elements/3), but my results aren't what they tell me to expect and I'm not getting errors either in build nor in the browser.

Relevant files are as follows:

```
<!-- nav-bar.html -->
<template bindable='router'>
  <require from="./user-status "></require>
  <!-- various nav buttons -->
  <p class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-text">
        Test <user-status></user-status>
      </p>
```

user-status.html

```
<template>
  ${status}
</template>
```

user-status.js

```
export default class UserStatusCustomElement {
      constructor() {
        this.status = 'Be sure to drink your Ovaltine!';
      }
    }
```

if I change the require in `nav-bar.html` to look for `./user-status.html` it appears to have an effect (additional aurelia-looking attributes are added to the user-status element in the rendered html) but does not render the message (one assumes b/c it's not picking up the class and rendering as an html-only thing).  If I leave as-is, it doesn't error but those attributes are not added and nothing is rendered, even static text.

Comment: Is it possible that the problem is occurring because of the extra space in `from="./user-status "`? Maybe try changing it to `from="./user-status"`? It might seem like a really silly suggestion, but I faced issues due to space in `repeat-for` iterator.

Comment: Another suggestion is, if you want to use just the html, then make the `status` `bindable` (like it is done in `nav-bar` for `router`), and bind the attribute from `nav-bar`.

Comment: Remove the `default` keyword from `user-status.js`.

Comment: @KellyEthridge that worked, though from everything I've read there's no reason it should be that way, and in fact my default eslinting config throws a warning when I *don't* have a default if I'm only exporting one thing.  Post an answer and I'll accept; if you can also explain *why* it has that behavior I will be forever in your debt.

Comment: Well I can't give a very good answer as I just experimented with your code. I don't know the internals of Aurelia very well. I'm sure it has something to do with how Aurelia leverages module-loaders such as `System.js`.

Comment: Well your comment should still be the answer, as it solved the problem and will be useful to others.  Also, it's worth noting that if you were using System.js; I was using webpack, so it's not an issue with the specific module-loader, but with how Aurelia is using them (as you said) or else something in the semantics of `export default` that I'm just not grokking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I played around with your code and found that removing `default` from the `user-status.js` module fixed the problem. I suspect the reason has something to do with how Aurelia utilizes module-loaders (`System.js`, `webpack`, ...) when importing modules. Unfortunately I don't know enough about the internals of Aurelia to give a more in-depth answer.

Comment: Thanks, I actually read a bit more on the import / export stuff and I think it's more correct to say that it's about how Aurelia imports viewmodels (independent of module loaders).  They want to support importing files that don't have a default export, and so to do that they have to import everything, and then assume the first thing exported is the viewmodel.  From what I can tell, doing that is not compatible with the default export / default import syntax.  That said, I'll file a bug in case someone smarter than me can figure it out. :)